# Get the details 1 week before the actual date

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have 3 tables as shown below.

1.

```
Services                        
--------------------------
ServiceID (PK,int)                    
SalesID (FK, int)                  
ItemName (varchar)            
FirstServiceDate (datetime)
```

2.

```
Sales              
------------------
SalesID (PK,int)  
CustomerID (FK,int)
SerialNo (varchar)
ModelNo (varchar)
```

and 3.

```
Customer
--------------------
CustomerID (PK,int)
CustName (varchar)
```

I am trying to get the details from service, sales and customer tables 1 week before FirstServiceDate's date. I tried below query. but it is not working as expected.

```
Select B.SalesID, C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName, B.SerialNo, B.ModelNo, 
A.FirstServiceDate from Services A inner join Sales B on 
A.SalesID = B.SalesID inner join Customer C on 
B.CustomerID = C.CustomerID and 
FirstServiceDate = DATEADD(week, 1, GETDATE())
```

If the FirstServiceDate is 2 March 2019, then 1 week before (i.e., on 23rd Feb - today). I should get notification.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: Please provide sample data and desired results.  Also explain what "1 week before first service date" really means.  What does the current date/time have to do with this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If the `FirstServiceDate` column is of type `DateTime` then you need to convert it to `Date`:

```
  select 
  B.SalesID, C.CustomerID, C.CustomerName, 
  B.SerialNo, B.ModelNo, A.FirstServiceDate 
  from Services A inner join Sales B 
  on A.SalesID = B.SalesID 
  inner join Customer C 
  on B.CustomerID = C.CustomerID 
  where convert(date, A.FirstServiceDate) = convert(date, dateadd(week, 1, getdate()))
```

this way the time part of the dates is eliminated and only the date part is compared. 
**Edit**: 
If you want the services scheduled for the next week, change the `where` part like this:

```
where 
  convert(date, A.FirstServiceDate) 
  between
    convert(date, getdate()) 
  and 
    convert(date, dateadd(week, 1, getdate()))
```

Comment: when using = in the where clause, i am not getting any result. But when i used <= , i am getting the rows. but the problem is - it is fetching data from DB more than 1 week ago dates also.

Comment: When you use `=` you will get the data that are **exactly** 1 week from today. Isn't this that you want? Do you have any data for the 3d of March?

Comment: suppose i saved the firstservicedate as 3rd March 2019 in DB. So today 24th Feb 2019 is exactly 1 week before the firstservicedate. So today I want to get the notification. That notification should exceed from today untill 3rd March. I need 1 weeks notification that is in between 24th Feb and 3rd March [include the day 24 and 3rd march also]

Comment: This is what you get with my edited code: dates between today up until 1 week from now.